# Unique Index except for one string

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

In SQL Server I want to create a column in an existing table that must have unique attributes with one exception: "ship". The table can contain exactly one copy of each element but when I insert "ship" again and again it should be fine. How can I manage that?

Comment: Instead of Trigger is one solution.

Comment: I was also going to suggest a trigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a **filtered** unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTable_YourColumn
ON dbo.YourTable(YourColumn)
WHERE ItemName <> 'ship'
```

This will enforce uniqueness for any value *other* than `ship`.

This works in SQL Server **2008** and newer